# Hex to int conversion of input data using C program

Tags: c, int, hex

I am trying to convert a hexadecimal data coming from a port( stored in a buffer) into integer format using C program. Before converting from buffer, I wanted to test my code by giving some input in the program. The following is the program I am using from a online source.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int hexToInt(char s[]) {
    int hexdigit, i, inhex, n;    
    i=0;

    if(s[i] == '0') {
        ++i;
        if(s[i] == 'x' || s[i] == 'X'){            
            ++i;
        }
    }

    n = 0;
    inhex = 1;
    for(; inhex == 1; ++i) {
        if(s[i] >= '0' && s[i] <= '9') {            
            hexdigit = s[i] - '0';
        } else if(s[i] >= 'a' && s[i] <= 'f') {            
            hexdigit = s[i] - 'a' + 10;
        } else if(s[i] >= 'A' && s[i] <= 'F') {
            hexdigit = s[i] - 'A' + 10;
        } else {
            inhex = 0;
        }

        if(inhex == 1) {
            n = 16 * n + hexdigit;
        }
    }

    return n;
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {

    char hex[] = "93 BC";
    int digit = hexToInt(hex);
    printf("The Integer is %d", digit);

    return 0;
}
```

When I run this program, it converts one input of hexadecimal into a integer. But if I had to convert an array of hex input as listed below:

```
00 00 00 05 00 00 00 01 93 BC C0 06 00 00 00 00         ................
00 28 17 00 FC 26 CC 62 00 00 00 07 00 00 00 01         .(...&.b........
00 00 00 D0 00 E3 37 19 00 00 00 1D 00 00 01 00         ......7.........
AB B6 CD 14 00 11 1F 3C 00 00 00 1D 00 00 00 00         .......<........
00 00 00 02 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 90 00 00 00 01         ................
00 00 05 EE 00 00 00 04 00 00 00 80 F0 92 1C 48         ...........�...H
C2 00 00 0E 0C 30 C7 C7 08 00 45 00 05 DC 32 70         .....0....E...2p
40 00 2D 06 41 C8 2D 3A 4A 01 93 BC C8 EC 01 BB         @.-.A.-:J.......
C1 58 C5 8D 53 88 05 72 46 E6 80 10 00 53 DC 34
```

Then how I can convert it into corresponding integer values?

Comment: 1) `int answer;` uninitialize. 2) `0X` not support in your code.

Comment: I'm amazed this even *compiles*! Surely it must at least generate a bunch of warnings ?

Comment: In main () or in hextoint method ??

Comment: It did not raise any warning except for the output I am getting.

Comment: Three warnings here for nested function, bad `main` declaration, etc. Maybe you don't have compiler warnings enabled ?

Comment: Paul, I have run C programs before in the same machine and I have received warnings...

Comment: Warning C4013: 'tolower' undefined; assuming extern returning int. Warning C4700: uninitialized local variable 'answer' used.

Comment: use [strtol](http://ideone.com/YXrTyO) instead of _a online source_

Comment: I have edited my question now for another query..please help me in understanding it.

Answer (score 0):

"to convert of array of hex input", modify `hexToInt()` to `hexToInt(const char *s, char **endptr)` and have it set `*endptr` to where the parsing stopped.  If no parsing occurred, have `*endptr = s`.

```
int main(void) {
  char hex[] = "93 BC";
  char *p = hex;
  while (*p) {
    char *endptr;  
    int digit = hexToInt(p, &endptr);
    if (p == endptr) break;
    printf("The Integer is %d", digit);
    p = endptr;
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the response. When I tried your solution for the input " 93 BC" as given in the program, I am getting value as 0.

Comment: In my case I am trying to convert the hex input which I have mentioned in my question below the C program. In my program I tried to first convert "93 BC" to see how the program responds.  but my original task is to convert the large hex input mentioned above. I need help in understanding it.

Comment: 1) `hexToInt()` needs to consume and ignore leading white-space: `while (isspace((unsgined char) s[i])) i++;`  2) The data after the 16 bytes in "00 28 17 00 FC 26 CC 62 00 00 00 07 00 00 00 01         .(...&.b........" should be ignored - it is redundant with the preceding data.  So limit the parsing to 16 bytes or until consecutive spaces occur.